# Group by column Django orm

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a database table `users` that consists of 4 columns `id,name,country,state` I will like to run an sql query like

```
SELECT country, state, name, COUNT(id) from users GROUP BY country, state, name
```

please how do i accomplish this using Django ORM

Comment: you can not group like that. If you `GROUP BY`, then the `SELECT` part only contains things in the `GROUP BY`, or aggregates.

Comment: It is also non-sensical. The response is a "flat" table, so what would that query mean?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: but that will still not work, it is either `SELECT country, state, name, COUNT(id) from users GROUP BY country, state, name`, or `SELECT country, COUNT(id) FROM users GROUP BY country`.

Comment: How do i achieve this using django orm

Comment: please share (relevant) parts of the model.

Comment: The model name is users, It consist of all those fields listed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a `QuerySet` with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Users.objects.values('country', 'state', 'name').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('country', 'state', 'name')
```

This will construct a queryset that is a collection of dictionaries, where each dictionary has four keys: `country`, `state`, `name` and `count`. The `count` is the total number of `Users` with the given `name`, `state` and `country` combination.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I have tried and this works, but displays the country id in the queryset, country field in the model is a foreign key from countries Model, which has fields country_name that I will like to display instead of country id

Comment: @doupix_9ja: then you use `'country__country_name'` in both `.values` and `.order_by`.

Comment: I've tried that previously and it returns the country name as ````country__country_name````, how do i return it as ````country```` instead. Thanks for your time

Comment: @doupix_9ja: you can't. `.values(...)` results in a "collapse" of the models, then it only contains raw data like strings, ints, etc. You can make an extra query to get the country for a given primary key.